Populate a blank row of data using a mutate(across(casewhen())) call to calculate values
I am attempting to merge two rows of data into one row of aggregated data. Much of the values in the two rows are the same. Where they differ, I want to append data together.
I started by using add_row() to create a new blank row that would serve as my target for aggregated data (with all NA values). Then, I tried to write a call that would evaluate the content of the two rows in each field. If they were the same, it would populate that value into the added blank row. If they were not the same, they would concatenate the values together with a separator.
I was able to get the code to evaluate each value in a column against the other value and return the output I wanted, but it overwrote the existing values in the original two rows, and did not populate into the blank third row I created. This is where I got stuck, and I'm not sure how to direct the code to populate the aggregated value into the blank cell of the created row.
I'm reluctant to pivot my data to create a new column to populate, and then to pivot it back because I don't want to lose my ID field (and I'm also perpetually bad at pivoting) but that might be the solution, unless there's a more elegant way to do it.
Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!
EDIT: With apologies for forgetting, this is my desired output:
 ID    Email                Gender Location    Ice_Cream_Flavor      
 1     janedoe@email.com    Female Los Angeles Strawberry
 2     jessicadoe@email.com Female Los Angeles Rocky Road
 NA    NA                   Female Los Angeles Strawberry; Rocky Road      

# Sample Data

library(tidyverse)

test<-data.frame("ID"=c("1","2"),
                 "Email"=c("janedoe@email.com","jessicadoe@email.com"),
                 "Gender"=c("Female","Female"),
                 "Location"=c("Los Angeles","Los Angeles"),
                 "Ice_Cream_Flavor"=c("Strawberry","Rocky Road"))
## Original Table

# A tibble: 2 × 5
  ID    Email                Gender Location    Ice_Cream_Flavor
  <chr> <chr>                <chr>  <chr>       <chr>           
1 1     janedoe@email.com    Female Los Angeles Strawberry      
2 2     jessicadoe@email.com Female Los Angeles Rocky Road 

## Attempted Code

merge<-test%>%
  add_row()%>%                                                                         # creating a new blank row to populate with aggregated data
  mutate(across(.cols = -c(`ID`,
                           `Email`),                                                   # calling up all columns except these specific ones    
                ~ case_when(!is.na(`ID`) & .[1]==.[2] ~ .[1],                          # Checking for equality in the values and returning the value in the first row
                            !is.na(`ID`) & .[1]!=.[2] ~ paste(.[1],.[2], sep = "; "),  # appending unequal values together
                            TRUE~NA)))

## Output

# A tibble: 3 × 5
  ID    Email                Gender Location    Ice_Cream_Flavor      
  <chr> <chr>                <chr>  <chr>       <chr>                 
1 1     janedoe@email.com    Female Los Angeles Strawberry; Rocky Road
2 2     jessicadoe@email.com Female Los Angeles Strawberry; Rocky Road
3 NA    NA                   NA     NA          NA       



Please post desired result. Should aggregation use Gender and Location as grouping columns?

I'm not sure about the desired output but it seems like you could merge the data frames as in test %>% merge(test, by = c("ID", "Email", "Gender", "Location"))

@Parfait desired output posted, apologies for the oversight. Thank you for the advice!

@TJ87 desired output posted, apologies for the oversight. I'll try merging the data frames and see what happens. Thanks!

Without pivoting one potential option is:
library(tidyverse)

test<-data.frame("ID"=c("1","2"),
               "Email"=c("janedoe@email.com","jessicadoe@email.com"),
               "Gender"=c("Female","Female"),
               "Location"=c("Los Angeles","Los Angeles"),
               "Ice_Cream_Flavor"=c("Strawberry","Rocky Road"))

test %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(length(unique(.x)) > 1, paste(.x, collapse = ";"), .x))) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  bind_rows(test, .)
#>    ID                                  Email Gender    Location      Ice_Cream_Flavor
#> 1   1                      janedoe@email.com Female Los Angeles            Strawberry
#> 2   2                   jessicadoe@email.com Female Los Angeles            Rocky Road
#> 3 1;2 janedoe@email.com;jessicadoe@email.com Female Los Angeles Strawberry;Rocky Road

Created on 2024-12-17 with reprex v2.1.0
Is that your desired outcome with this example dataset? Or have I misunderstood?

This is very close to my desired outcome. The only difference is that I wanted to exclude the ID and Email columns from being evaluated and appended. I believe my original code of calling mutate(across(.cols = -c(ID, Email)...)) would take care of that requirement. Thank you! Also apologies for forgetting my desired output in the question.

Glad you solved your problem @MaryRachel

I'm not 100% clear on what the result should look like, but the code below uses summarise() to combine the 2 rows, and bind_rows() to add it to the original data:
library(tidyverse)

test<-data.frame("ID"=c("1","2"),
                 "Email"=c("janedoe@email.com","jessicadoe@email.com"),
                 "Gender"=c("Female","Female"),
                 "Location"=c("Los Angeles","Los Angeles"),
                 "Ice_Cream_Flavor"=c("Strawberry","Rocky Road"))

# Helper function to use in summarise
combine <- function(a) {
  if(a[1] == a[2]) {
    a[1]
  } else {
    paste(a[1], a[2], sep = "; ")
  }
}

# add the summarised row to your original data
merge <- test %>%
  bind_rows(
    summarise(test, across(-c(ID, Email), combine))
  )

merge
    ID                Email Gender    Location       Ice_Cream_Flavor
1    1    janedoe@email.com Female Los Angeles             Strawberry
2    2 jessicadoe@email.com Female Los Angeles             Rocky Road
3 <NA>                 <NA> Female Los Angeles Strawberry; Rocky Road


This is very elegant! I'm a little unsure of myself when it comes to writing helper functions, but this is my desired output. Thank you! Also apologies for forgetting to include my desired output in the question.

I'm afraid it threw an error: Error in summarise():
ℹ In argument: across(...).
Caused by error in if (a[1] == a[2]) ...:
! the condition has length > 1
Run rlang::last_trace() to see where the error occurred.

rlang::last_trace()
<error/rlang_error>
Error in summarise():
ℹ In argument: across(...).
Caused by error in if (a[1] == a[2]) ...:
! the condition has length > 1



Are you running it on different input data? If so could you post a sample of the data which is causing the problem. When I run it on the test data frame, it gives the output above.

Consider a base R solution with aggregate, rbind, and sort_by with some NA assignment:
agg <- aggregate(
  Ice_Cream_Flavor ~ Gender + Location,
  data = test,
  FUN=\(s) paste(s, collapse = "; "),
  na.action = na.pass
) |> transform(
  ID = NA, Email = NA
)

final <- rbind(test, agg) |> sort_by(~ Gender + Location) |> `row.names<-`(NULL)
final

#     ID                Email Gender    Location       Ice_Cream_Flavor
# 1    1    janedoe@email.com Female Los Angeles             Strawberry
# 2    2 jessicadoe@email.com Female Los Angeles             Rocky Road
# 3 <NA>                 <NA> Female Los Angeles Strawberry; Rocky Road
# 4    3    johndoe@email.com   Male     Chicago              Chocolate
# 5    4  jeremydoe@email.com   Male     Chicago                Vanilla
# 6 <NA>                 <NA>   Male     Chicago     Chocolate; Vanilla

Data (extended for multiple grouping demonstration)
test <- data.frame(
  "ID" = c("1","2","3","4"),
  "Email" = c("janedoe@email.com", "jessicadoe@email.com","johndoe@email.com","jeremydoe@email.com"),
  "Gender" = c("Female","Female","Male","Male"),
  "Location" = c("Los Angeles","Los Angeles","Chicago","Chicago"),
  "Ice_Cream_Flavor" = c("Strawberry","Rocky Road","Chocolate","Vanilla")
)

